# Heat diffuser for ceramic cooktop

Tags: equipment, ceramic

I have seen similar questions on here, but not directly answering my question. I recently purchased a tagine, which is a ceramic slow cooker. It comes with, and says to use a diffuser when cooking on the cooktop. But the diffuser that came with it says not to use it on ceramic tops, as it may scratch.

Does anyone have any idea what type is best? I did some research online (which is actually how I found this site), but could not find any explicit answers about it, except that the cast iron diffuser I found also said not to use it on a ceramic top.

**Edit**: Thank you, Joe. I had already seen those posts before I posted the question. They agree that you should use a diffuser, but no explicit information on what material diffuser to use. I am hoping someone would be able to say: "use a brass diffuser" (or some material that actually would work on my ceramic cook top).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/21254/67 .  and for the cast iron diffuser : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/4734/67

Comment: I'm not saying that they answer the question, just that they're related.  I'd personally look for a diffuser that's coated in some way, so it's less likely to scratch the cooktop.  Based on the cast iron on a glass range question, (and experience), I'd probably go for the cast iron, but make sure it was well seasoned.

Comment: Ceramic is brittle and will scratch.  I doubt you are going to find one.  But good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a aluminum plate or disc that your tagine can sit on. The plate needs a minimum thickness of 0.25 inch, any thinner and it may badly warp. The aluminum will heat very evenly, conduct heat better than cast iron, is much softer than glass or ceramic, and is much lighter than brass or cast iron.

Just don't leave it by itself on the stove, it can be damaged by overheating, similar to overheating other aluminum based cookware.

You can buy 6061 aluminum plates at metal suppliers, and even online at places like amazon.